# Capybara select from dropdown with regular expression?

Tags: regex, select, drop-down-menu, capybara

I am trying to scrape a web page with Capybara, which is working fine, except that I am having trouble with a certain page.  It has a dropdown list defined with the following HTML:

```
<select onChange="this.form.submit();" id="AcctNumber" name="AcctNum">
<option value="MU:P2" selected="true">Investment &nbsp;-&nbsp;2845</option>
<option value="MU:P0">Patrick UGMA&nbsp;-&nbsp;1585</option>
<option value="MU:P1">Lisa UGMA&nbsp;-&nbsp;1655</option>
```

I have tried to select a value with many variations on this theme

```
selector = 'Investment - 2845'
selector = 'Investment &nbsp;-&nbsp; 2845'
selector = 'Investment    &nbsp;-&nbsp;   2845'
select selector, :from => "AcctNumber"
```

all of which (and many more) produce `ElementNotFound` errors.

Is there a way to just use a regular expression, say `/Invest/` or `/Pat/` or `/Lisa/` to
select the item?  It sure would be easier than trying to guess what literal string will
match the mysterious whitespace around those hyphens.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is likely that there *is* no white-space around the hyphens. The `&nbsp;` is a non-breaking space character when rendered in the browser - but when read by a screen-scraper, it is 6 characters. "`&nbsp;`".

This means that when you try to match it with a screen-scraper, you should likely try to match the HTML, not the rendered version.

The second thing I noticed from your cut'n'paste was that there were tab characters around them. Tabs and spaces, in RegEx, are both matched using the `\s` selector.

Try this RegEx as a start:

```
(Investment|Patrick|Lisa)[\s]*(&nbsp;)[-](&nbsp;)[\s]*[0-9](,4)
```

This starts by matching the word "Investment" OR "Patrick" OR "Lisa" - then any amount of white-space (spaces, tabs, etc) - then the literal " ", a dash, the literal " " again, any amount of spaces again, and then 4 digits 0-9.

**Note:** *I have not tested this RegEx.* However, it should give you a good starting point to build from. I suggest [Regular-Expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) if you need more help adjusting it.

Comment: Thanks, Troy.  My question was more basic.  Can I use a regex in place of a string in first argument to the select method?  And I only want to select one of the possibilities, so /Investment/ should work, but I still get ElementNotFound.

Comment: Hmm - I'm not particularly familiar with Capybara - so I'm not sure what that comes from. Is it possible to have Capybara call a client-side script? Or use a jQuery-type selector?

Comment: Yes.  Good thought, though I know nothing about jQuery, yet.